# Is it possible to fire an onLoad event after a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fire an `onLoad` event after updating the `body` tag with additional attributes. This happens when the user clicks on an item.

The attribute gets added to the body tag, but nothing happens. How can I fix this?

```
$('#about-link').click(function () {
    $("body").attr("onLoad","outputXML('about-content', 'assets/xml/sample.xml', 'assets/xsl/sample.xsl');");
    onload();
});
```

Comment: What you want to do is call the function attached to the onload event

Comment: How would I do that? The code is here: http://pastebin.com/TQspddkZ

Comment: Where is the HTML? it would show the onload in the body tag.

Comment: The HTML does not have the onLoad originally, I add it when `#about-link` is clicked

Comment: So what set of action are supposed to take place when you add the attributes?

Comment: @colecmc - ahh I've just figured it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load events happen when a resource and its dependent resources have finished loading.

If you want something to fire when a user clicks something, use a click (and/or touch and/or pointer) event instead, or (in your case) perhaps call the function in whatever code is adding the additional attributes to the `body` tag (which itself was probably triggered by one of these events).

- [More information on load events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load)
- [More information on click events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click)
- [More information on touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)
- [Spec for pointer events](http://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/)
- [Support matrix for pointer events](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. This works.

```
$('#about-link').click(function () {
    window.showCorrectPage('#about', '#about-li');
    outputXML('about-content', 'assets/xml/sample.xml', 'assets/xsl/sample.xsl');
});
```